# Add function after the_content

Tags: plugin-development, loop, the-content

I have the following function within a simple plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Social buttons
 */
function zss_social_buttons() {
?>
    <div class="zss">
        <!-- Facebook -->
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
            (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-lazy="true">
        </div>
        <!-- Twitter -->
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;text=<?php echo urlencode( get_the_title() ); ?>" title="Share on Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" class="zss-button zss-button--twitter">Twitter</a>
        <!-- LinkedIn -->
        <a class="zss-button zss-button--linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Share on LinkedIn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">LinkedIn</a>
        <!-- E-Mail -->
        <a class="zss-button zss-button--email" href="mailto:?subject=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;body=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Share by Email" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Email</a>
    </div>
<?php }
```

I'd like my social share buttons to appear underneath `the_content()` via each single post. To achieve this, I've built the following filter hook in the same plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Insert share button
 */ 
function zss_insert_share_buttons( $content ) {
    if ( is_singular() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
        $social_share_buttons = zss_social_buttons();
        $content .= $social_share_buttons;
        return $content;
    }
    else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'zss_insert_share_buttons' );
```

For some reason, the `zss_social_buttons()` function loads before `the_content();`. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: `zss_social_buttons()` echo the output instead of returning it, hence it's not actually added to `$content` and instead the output is displayed immediately.

Comment: Thanks, @SallyCJ. Can you demonstrate this in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your code is caused by the call to `zss_social_buttons()` in your filter function:

```php
// In zss_insert_share_buttons():

$social_share_buttons = zss_social_buttons(); // NULL
$content .= $social_share_buttons;
```

And the problem there is that `zss_social_buttons()` is echoing the sharing links/buttons instead of returning them, so they're not actually added to the `$content` variable. Instead, they're sent to the browser (or displayed) immediately when the function runs.

So that explains why the buttons appear before the post content. ( That's what you meant by "*the `zss_social_buttons()` function loads before `the_content();`*", right? )

Additionally, the Facebook script and including the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` should be added only once and not every time the filter `the_content` is applied. So for example, you can use the [`wp_body_open` (action) hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_body_open/) to add the script right after the `<body>` tag:

```php
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'my_wp_body_open' );
function my_wp_body_open() {
    ?>
        <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>put the script code here</script>
    <?php
}
```

And then, to fix the main issue, you can either:

- Make the `zss_social_buttons()` function returns the output and not echoing it. Simplified example:

  ```php
  <?php
  function zss_social_buttons() {
      return '<div class="zss">
          <!-- Facebook -->
          <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '"' .
              ' data-layout="button_count" data-lazy="true"></div>

          ... your other buttons.
      </div>';
  }
  ```
- Or you can use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) in the `zss_insert_share_buttons()` function:

  ```
  <?php
  function zss_social_buttons() {
      ?>
          <div class="zss">
              <!-- Facebook -->
              <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
                  data-layout="button_count" data-lazy="true"></div>

              ... your other buttons.
          </div>
      <?php
  }

  function zss_insert_share_buttons( $content ) {
      if ( is_singular() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
          ob_start();

          zss_social_buttons(); // echo the output, but send it to the buffer and
                                // not the browser

          $content .= ob_get_clean(); // and then append the buffer to $content
      }

      return $content;
  }
  ```

Comment: Not only did you offer an excellent answer, but you improved my code. You're awesome, thank you.